# Flex: Capitalize words in string?

Tags: apache-flex, capitalization

I am trying to do the equivalent of PHP's ucwords() in Flex. I dont want the whole string in uppercase just the first letter of each word. Does anyone know a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the same as Rafael's answer but with no warnings :)

```
str.replace(/\b./g,function(...m):String{return m[0].toUpperCase()});
```

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
str.replace(/\b./g,function(m){return String(m).toUpperCase()});
```

explanation:

the regex /\b./g matches a word boundary followed by any character. All matches will be passed to the anonymous function defined in second parameter of replace method. The function returns the match capitalized.

Comment: Hi your code works great, but you had 1 error I needed to fix, you have 1 too many ) at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer assumes that the string is all lower-case to start with. If you start with a string with all upper-case or random mixed-cases, this will not work.

Here is a simple modification that does not require the source string to be all lower-case to begin with:

```
str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b./g,function(...m):String{return m[0].toUpperCase()});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems with special characters in Portuguese, so I changed it to this RegExp:

```
str.replace(/(^|\s|\t)+\S/g, function(...m):String{return m[0].toUpperCase()});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to get past some errors and warnings:

str.replace(/\b./g,function(m:String):String{return m.toUpperCase()});

but it gave me a strange crash, saying that it had three parameters when only one was expected.

I tried to fix the regex, but my regex-fu is not great. So I punted. This works (at least, for the first word in a string). For multiple words, you'd have to use the split.

str = str.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1,str.length);

Comment: I got the same error when I tried to do that too, but leaving it the way Rafael made it works.

Comment: I finally figured out how to make this work without any errors or warnings: str.replace(/\b./g,function(...m):String{return m[0].toUpperCase()});